The prejudice of objective thought
Merleau-Ponty talks about the prejudice of objective thought. Does this relate to the idea in phenomenology that to fully understand phenomena (the "thing itself") we need to suspend the natural attitude?

Yes, but. The natural attitude is what we implicitly adopt in practice when going about our everyday business. Merleau-Ponty in Phenomenology of Perception talks about its refined and explicit philosophical derivatives, empiricism and idealism, "before developing a third way that avoids the problematic assumption common to both, namely, their “unquestioned belief in the world”: the prejudice that the objective world exists as a ready-made and fully present reality." SEP.

Thank you. This is helpful. So the natural attitude, from a Merleau-Ponty perspective, does involve the prejudice of objective thought if our thinking is grounded in empiricism or idealism. Correct? I still wonder why my question was flagged. Can you explain as I am new to this forum.

@andrós The diction may seem odd to you, but Continental philosophy has a very different mindset and vocabulary than analytic philosophy.

It seems safe to say that Merleau-Ponty considered objective thought a prejudice or bias (Luft, 1998; Morris, 2003). The questioner (myself, @jant17) asks how this relates to the notion of the natural attitude.
Starting with what Merleau-Ponty meant by objective thought... In his Phenomenology of Perception Merleau-Ponty (2013) states “that in order to reach this goal (the phenomenological return to phenomena) one must question logic and classical philosophy’s “objective thought,” suspend the categories of the world, doubt (in the Cartesian sense) the supposed facts of realism, and proceed to a genuine phenomenological reduction. Objective thought or thought applied to the universe and not to phenomena, knows only dichotomies; …” (p. 50 [M-P p. 75-76]). According to Merleau-Ponty then, objective thought is aligned to categorisation and a realist view of the world, attitudes which provide certainties associated with the natural attitude.
But what is this natural attitude? In brief, we might say that the natural attitude is one of unquestioning everydayness, a kind of natural, normal, naivety—it is called a natural attitude because we are unaware that we are in it. Things and entities within it are as if given to us. When we question the natural attitude, we are immediately in another attitude, possibly a scientific attitude whereby objective rather than relative truths are important. When the world does not correspond to our view of reality, whether our attitude is naive (what Luft refers to as a home attitude, where we feel most ‘at home’), and/or scientific, we generally believe the world continues to exist (Luft, 1998). This is the realist belief that our life generally rests upon.
There are, according to Luft, many natural attitudes. Since we may not be aware of being in the natural attitude, Merleau-Ponty favours the application of thought in genuine “phenomenological reduction”.
Morris: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00071773.2003.11863839
Luft: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010034512821

Though I'm more inclined to use Sellars's term 'manifest image' given my readings in analytic philosophy, it looks like Merleau-Ponty has some similar ideas in his Phenomenology of Perception.
If we review this Notre Dame review of a recent translation, we find that he discusses the objective and pre-objective aspects of being, and that the natural attitude refers to the everyday, pre-reflective way we experience the world. I would take this state roughly to mean the psychology and philosophy of naive realism. In this state, we take our perceptions and experiences for granted, without questioning or thinking about them deeply. Like a lot of Continental philosophers who insist on the first-person view of philosophy, he tries to describe these experiences as they are lived, rather than explaining or analyzing them from an external perspective, something those of us in the analytic tribes tend to do. (This is related to what Sellars would call this the 'scientific image'). In this case, the "prejudice of objective thought" would be the illusion that there is an objective perspective of ourselves and the world which is free of our experience and values. (On a shallow reading is what Sellars would call the 'Myth of the Given'.)
You ask:

Does this relate to the idea in phenomenology that to fully understand phenomena (the "thing itself") we need to suspend the natural attitude?

If we look to Dorfman's review we see that there is an interplay between the pre-objective and objective aspects. Dorfman writes:

every description of the body as pre-objective is always complemented by a description of the same body as objective or objectified. It is true that this objectification is sometimes attributed to science or to pathology... The body is never completely pre-objective nor completely objective, but instead moves between these two aspects. It is precisely this constant movement which Merleau-Ponty names ambiguity.

Going back to Kant, we can draw a distinction between the phenomenal and noumenal. The phenomenal is experience from the first-person, and the noumenal which might be understood as the "objective fiction" of things existing independently of us (das Ding an sich), which can be accepted or rejected, but certainly inaccessible to us since all of us are trapped by our imperfect, subjective perceptions. It's bringing together these two realms, the sensory experience of first person and the mind-independent aspects of the world (as far as I understand it as a non-phenomenologist) that might be thought of as being a transcendental act.
Thus, according to these sources, it looks like Merleau-Ponty was concerned that one must seek out how to reconcile the pre-objective and objective and not place too much emphasis on either on pain of fragmenting the full range of human experience. Dealing with this "ambiguity" seems to be his focus. It also doesn't seem to be that far distant from Husserl's notion of bracketing which is stripping away, presumably the objective truths thrust upon one by one's society to see the world really as it is, which I would take as pre-objective in Merleau-Ponty's terminology. In this sense, what is "objective" is really what might be termed intersubjective agreement that we are indoctrinated with by our society in a manner roughly consistent with The Social Construction of Reality by Berger and Luckmann.
